# indemt error in index.jade

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am using angular.js and i have used polls code.
Below is the code of index.jade:

```
doctype html
 html(lang='en')
 head 
 meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no') 
  title= title 
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/ css/bootstrap.min.css') 
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js') 
  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js')
   body 
   nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
    div.navbar-header
     a.navbar-brand(href='#/polls')= title
      div.container 
      div
```

While running the code i am getting error as:

2
 1| doctype html 
 > 2| html(lang='en') 
 3| head 
 4| meta(charset='utf-8') 
 5| meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no') 
unexpected token "indent"

```
1| doctype html
> 2| html(lang='en')
3| head
4| meta(charset='utf-8')
5| meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no')
unexpected token "indent"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html(...) should not be indented (same level as doctype):

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
```

Comment: i have removed 'html' from doctype, but still getting the same issue

Comment: Don't remove the "html" from doctype. Just remove the 2 spaces in front of "html(lang='en')".

Comment: getting another problem: '3| head <br/> 4| meta(charset='utf-8') <br/> > 5| meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no') <br/> 6| title= title <br/> 7| link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css') <br/> 8| link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css') <br/><br/>meta is self closing and should not have content'

Comment: Add two spaces in front of `meta(charset='utf-8')`.